# How to block an element

Tags: css, user-interface

I have a web application that displays a bunch of content and I want some of the elements to have a 50% transparent image over them so that the user can see whats in there but cannot access it.

Can this be done with CSS?

I have looked at jQuery BlockUI but I doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: this is a horrible way to accomplish this from a html and interface perspective (unnecessary images for non-IE browsers and potential accessibility issues). I'd recommend the input disabled="disabled" method and customising the style of it via CSS - e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kqPjt/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to prevent someone from clicking a checkbox or select box, it's much better to set the attribute `disabled="disabled"` instead.

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/K42VU/)

---

However if you insist on blocking it with another element, you could use `relative` and `absolute` positioning with a wrapper div with the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <select><option>Disabled</option></select>
    <div class="blocker"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.wrap { position:relative; }
.blocker {
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
}
```

[See example →](http://jsfiddle.net/K42VU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an element with CSS like this:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;

height: 100%;
width: 100%;

background: black;
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50)
```

Comment: That doesn't do the trick unfortunately. I need the black opacity to prevent the user from clicking form elements (checkbox/drop down)

Comment: @Michael: I forgot `z-index: 1234567`.  Also, make sure that the element doesn't have any positioned parents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Just ensure that the elements that need to be in front have a higher z-index than the elements that must be behind them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting a little closer but the background is still behind the element. The opacity is working fine. Also I can still click the checkboxes in the elements that are supposed to be blocked.